# Unable to access web api remotely

Tags: json, ssl, proxy, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have a `Web api` which I have deployed on the server. Now when I try to access it locally or giving the `IP`, via `postman` in the server, i am able to get a response message. The response is like below in `JSON`

```
{
"data": {
    "Response": "No" // or it can be Yes
 }
}
```

Now when I try to access it remotely (at my system) via postman, I am getting the following message

> Could not get any response
>   There was an error connecting to http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:8080/api/meters/GetByMsn/002999000043/2017-12-11T17:38:57.
>   Why this might have happened:
>   The server couldn't send a response:
>   Ensure that the backend is working properly
>   Self-signed SSL certificates are being blocked:
>   Fix this by turning off 'SSL certificate verification' in Settings > General
>   Proxy configured incorrectly
>   Ensure that proxy is configured correctly in Settings > Proxy
>   Request timeout:
>   Change request timeout in Settings > General

For this I have searched many articles/questions, but couldn't able to solve my issue

The solutions are mentioned below

1. [Could not get any response](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3127)
2. [Call to localhost:8000 "Could not get any response"](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2214)
3. ["Could not get any response" from servers with SSL issues](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1504)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not set the firewall to allow port access?